# Many to Many with Discriminator - No Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have at least four entities like so

```
public class Item {
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Prices;
    . . . . 
}


public class OtherThing {
    public int ThingID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Price> Prices;
    . . . . 
}
```

There is no base class for the four entities.  Let's just assume they aren't similar enough to have a base class.

I also have this entity:

```
public class Price {
    public int PriceID { get; set; }
    . . . .
}
```

The goal is to be able to get a `Set<Item>()` or `Set<OtherThing>()`, and have the Prices hydrated with the correct prices.

One idea is to make an ItemPrice Table and an OtherThingPrice table, but these tables would be identical and change together, so that idea is thrown out.

Another idea is to use TPH, but Price isn't a base class of these four+ tables, so it seems semantically wrong, and I am not sure it would even work (would it?)

The thought is to do something like this:

```
public class PriceMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Price>
{
    public PriceMap()
    {
        Map<Item>(m => m....);
        Map<OtherThing>(m => m....);
    }
}
```

But all information about that is regarding base classes.  Can this apply to a Many to Many relationship?  I imagine ending up with a Many-Many mapping table which looks like:

```
EntityToPriceTable
    EntityToPriceID
    EntityID
    EntityType
    PriceID
```

Comment: what about inheritance : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Well, Item, OtherThing, Thingie3, etc are not Types of Price.  They aren't technically a type of anything relatable, other than the fact that they all Have a Many-Many relationship with Prices.  Hence why the title says "No Inheritance"

Comment: What's the problem with separate implicit link tables? EF will maintain them automatically for you (no special intermediate entities are needed). This is the easiest in case `Item`, `OtherThing` etc. have no common base entity (table).

Comment: Ivan wow... Seems too simple to have been missed...  Classic case of over complicating... Maybe. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @IvanStoev I feel that I'm asking too much.  My complaint is that the PriceEntity now has to have a bunch of Collections of each of the Many-Many relationships shared with it.  Seems illogical to cry about that because it makes sense, but `:(`.  The question with this approach becomes: How can I take a PriceID, and pull all Things associated with that price?  We hadn't planned to go in that direction, but what if?

Comment: Hi mate, not a problem at all :) (1) It doesn't necessarily need to. The associations could be unidirectional with navigation property only at the other entity ends (like `modelBuilder.Entity<Item>.HasMany(e => e.Prices).WithMany();` etc.) (2) That could be a problem if it's needed at some point. You can do some manual union queries with projecting the common data, but it would be a pain. So in case you need something like this, than better introduce a common base entity like `PriceableEntity` (:-), unify the PK and other common property names, and use either TPH or TPT.

Comment: @IvanStoev Gotcha.  Just a placeholder base class with naught more than the relationship info for Price.  I like Option 1, and will push for admittance that you never need to go from a Price to an Item or OtherThing (in our case).